# Can anyone help me understand my 2d movement script in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMove : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public Transform spawn;
    public Vector2 moveforward;
    public Vector2 jumpheight;
    public Vector3 turn;

    void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.collider.tag == "Floor")
        {
        //Move
            if (Input.GetKeyDown("w"))
            {
                rb.AddForce(jumpheight * Time.deltaTime);
            }

            if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
            {
                rb.AddForce(jumpheight * Time.deltaTime);
            }            
        }

        //Death
        if (collision.collider.tag == "Death")
        {
            transform.position = spawn.position;
        }
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //Move
        if (Input.GetKey("d"))
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(turn);
            rb.AddForce(moveforward * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("a"))
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(-turn);
            rb.AddForce(-moveforward * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

I came up with this now for my 2d platformer.
I hate it when it says mostly code.
I hate it when it says mostly code.I hate it when it says mostly code.I hate it when it says mostly code.I hate it when it says mostly code.I hate it when it says mostly code.I hate it when it says mostly code.I hate it when it says mostly code.I hate it when it says mostly code.I hate it when it says mostly code.I hate it when it says mostly code.

Comment: and what exactly is your problem? Where **specifically** do you have difficulties?

Comment: I'm using Free Pixel Space Platform Pack and when I walk off an edge I tilt slowly then fall. Any alternatives to this code new code.

Answer (score 0):

Rigidbody component on your object keeps track of objects "Velocity" which is " speed" on each axis.
Velocity is Vector3 with x value,y value,z value for each axis( Vector2 just doesn't modify z)
AddForce is incrementing each of those 3 properties of Velocity by corresponding x,y,z values you are " adding". time.deltaTime is jsut to distribute added force over time.

Comment: I'm using  Free Pixel Space Platform Pack and when I walk off an edge I tilt slowly then fall. Any alternatives to this code.

Answer (score 0):

try this. rigidbody2D has 3 dimension when you are putting it like AddForce(value); it implements on X,Z,Y aswell, so instead of it try to give value only to first parameter of Addforce function which is X. hope it will help. also sorry for my bad english :)

```html
 void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //Move
        if (Input.GetKey("d"))
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(turn);
            rb.AddForce(moveforward * Time.deltaTime,0f,0f);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("a"))
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(-turn);
            rb.AddForce(-moveforward * Time.deltaTime,0f,0f);
        }
    }
```